# couldn't build app using DMSDK (data movement SDK) with maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, marklogic, marklogic-9

I'm trying to use Marklogic DMSDK (Data Movement SDK) in java because I want to load content with dynamic paramters.  I'm using Marklogic 9.0-8. I kind of followed the sample provided by

```
https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/data-movement-sdk
```

I use maven to build java app with java 1.8 on windows 10. But when I tried to build, I got the following errors. This error also happened on the sample code.

```
[INFO] Building loaddata 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] Downloading from : https://developer.marklogic.com/maven2/com/burgstaller/okhttp-digest/1.16/okhttp-digest-1.16.pom
[INFO] Downloading from : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/burgstaller/okhttp-digest/1.16/okhttp-digest-1.16.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.346 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-22T13:50:23-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project loaddata: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.asme.publish:loaddata:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.marklogic:marklogic-client-api:jar:4.1.2 -> com.burgstaller:okhttp-digest:jar:1.16: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.burgstaller:okhttp-digest:jar:1.16: Could not transfer artifact com.burgstaller:okhttp-digest:pom:1.16 from/to MarkLogic-releases (https://developer.marklogic.com/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
```

The following are some pieces from my pom.xml

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
      <id>MarkLogic-releases</id>
      <name>MarkLogic Releases</name>
      <url>https://developer.marklogic.com/maven2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>marklogic-client-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks a lot,
Helen

Answer (score 3):

I found the link 
https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/817

based on this link, I added the following to my pom.xml file

```
<repository>
    <id>jcenter</id>
    <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
</repository>
```

seems I can build app now.

Comment: I can build app now, but when I ran the app, I keeping getting error: "com.marklogic.client.ResourceNotFoundException: Local message: Could not read resource at internal/forestinfo. Server Message: 404 Not Found" .  I don't think this is a working way

Comment: that sounds like the app missed the target while trying to communicate with MarkLogic. Maybe it didn't specify the host correctly, or the port, or it specified a REST extension that hadn't been deployed. I'd need more info about how your app is trying to talk to MarkLogic. Sounds like it might be another question.

Comment: I studied the java client API part. and it works for me now. it was because the http server I setup didn't support the rest API.